# Stop two way databinding on model

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm fairly new to Angular so if there is some incorrect thinking here, please let me know.

I'm trying to create two separate scope variables based on the same data set.  I assumed that I would just be able to set them to different variables (as shown below) and it would work.  I've found, however, that no matter what they are named or how they are defined (even in a directive!) that changing one changes them all.

So...what I expect/would like to see is that if I change the input in the top repeat it will only change the model for that repeat.  Currently it changes all three.

Where am I going wrong here?  I assume this has something to do with the two way data-binding.  Thanks in advance!

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xQnx9JQ0NK9bWgNE0SKm?p=preview)

HTML:

```
 <h4>data</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="person in data">
      {{person.name}}
      <input ng-model="person.name" />
    </div>
    {{data[0].name}}
    <br>
    <br>

    <h4>testData</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="person in testData">
      {{person.name}}
      <input ng-model="person.name" />
    </div>
    {{testData[0].name}}

    <h4>Directive</h4>
    <div tester data="data"></div>
```

Directive HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data">
  {{person.name}}
  <input ng-model="person.name" />
</div>
{{data[0].name}}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

(function () {

    var testController = function ($scope) {

      var data = [
        {name:'Jordan', age:30},
        {name:'Sean', age:32},
        {name:'Seth', age:26}
      ];

      $scope.data = data;

      $scope.testData = data;
    }    

    testController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

    app.controller('testController', testController);


}())

app.directive('tester', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        //If percent = true then that table should have a "percent change" th
        scope:{
            data: '=data'
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I'm trying to create two separate scope variables based on the same
>   data set. I assumed that I would just be able to set them to different
>   variables (as shown below) and it would work

Actually both those javascript variables are pointing to the same data structure in memory. So when you modify this structure it reflects to both of them. Think of those `data` and `testData` variables as pointers to the same data.

You could [`copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) this data structure in order to create 2 different instances of it in memory so that changes to one do not reflect to changes of the other:

```
$scope.data = data;
$scope.testData = angular.copy(data);
```

and if you wanted to reflect this in your directive, go ahead and clone the instance you are passing to it as well:

```
<div tester data="angular.copy(data)"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is exactly what I was looking for.  Nailed it.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me!

Comment: hah, no way...I ran into this exact problem yesterday. Wish I knew about this yesterday!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Awesome solution

Answer (score 0):

Here both data and testData pointing to the same reference that why they are replicating same value.There are 2 solutions we can apply if there is function references, date object, and any undefined values which need to be there in the object after copy then appropriate option is **$scope.testData = agular.copy(data);**
Another options **$scope.testData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));** but following keys won't be copyed.

1. functions.
2. Date object
3. properties with the value undefined