# How to stop two way data binding for ng-model in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to stop two way data binding for ng-model in Angularjs?

[Reference Image added please click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8xha.png)

Comment: Simple, you may need to avoid reference of a `model` inside another model! Solution: _use `angular.copy()`_ to add new row to your existing array of object

Comment: check below link it may help you
[url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244053/stop-two-way-databinding-on-model)

Comment: are you using same ng-model for both answers?

Comment: Yes Nikhil.....

Comment: either you need to create a directive that accepts answers in different variable or you should use different ng-model variables

Comment: @Kranthi did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Below example will give you some understanding over one time binding which you can achieve by using `::` like this  `{{::scopeObject}}`

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.name1 = 'Vikram';
  $scope.name2 = 'Angular';
  
  });
```

```html
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="name1" /> 
  {{::name1}} - One way binding
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="name2" /> 
  {{name2}} - Two way binding
  </div>
```